# Problem in string concatenation in sql server using FOR XML Path. 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the below data

```
UniqueID    ID  data
1       1   a
2       1   2
3       1   b
4       1   1
5       2   d
6       2   3
7       2   r
```

The expected output being

```
ID  ConcatData
1   a,-,-,b,-
2   d,-,-,-,r
```

What we have to do is that, the number of numeric charecters has to be replaced with those many dashes('-') and then we need to merge the data for the respective id's.

I am using the below query so far

```
declare @t table(UniqueID int identity(1,1), ID int, data varchar(10))  
insert into @t select 1, 'a' union all  select 1, '2' union all select 1, 'b' 
union all select 1, '1' union all select 2, 'd' union all select 2, '3' 
union all select 2, 'r' 

select * from @t

;with cte1 as 
(     
    select 
        UniqueId
        , id
        , data
        , case when isnumeric(data) = 1 then cast(data as int) end Level
         from @t     
    union all     
    select 
        UniqueId
        , id
        , CAST('-' as varchar(10))
        , Level - 1     
    from cte1     
    where Level > 0 ) 
,cte2 as
(
select id, GroupID = Dense_Rank() Over(Order by id),data, DataOrder = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by UniqueID, Level)
from cte1 
where Level is null or data = '-' 
) 

SELECT
ID
, (select data + ',' 
from cte2 t2 
where t2.GroupID = t1.GroupID
for XML path('')
) as ConcatData
from cte2 t1
group by t1.ID ,t1.GroupID
```

But the output is

```
ID  ConcatData
1   a,b,-,-,-,
2   d,r,-,-,-,
```

That is I am not able to position the dashes('-') in between the characters.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte1 as
(
select 
UniqueId
, id
, data
,case when isnumeric(data) = 1 
    THEN replicate(',-',data) 
    ELSE ',' + data end as string
from @t
)

select 
id
,LTRIM(STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ' ' + t2.String
    FROM Cte1 t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 2, 1, ''
  )) As concatenated_string
from cte1 t1 group by t1.ID ,t1.ID
```

Works for the sample data bove and might be a bit quicker than using cursors

Comment: Thanks got to learn new thing about replicate. I agree, Your suggestion is better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the table creating

```
Create table #temp
(
    IDUnique int Identity(1,1),
    ID int, 
    data varchar(100)
)
```

Following are the records suggested by you.

```
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(1, 'a')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(1, '2')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(1, 'b')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(1, '1')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(2, 'd')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(2, '3')
Insert into #temp(ID, data) Values(2, 'r')
```

[image]

Following is the cursor implementation

```
declare @IDUnique int
declare @ID int
declare  @data varchar(100)
declare @Latest int
declare @Previous int
declare @Row int

set @Latest = 1
set @Previous = 1

Create Table #temp1
(
    ID int,
    data varchar(100)
)

--SELECT Row_Number() Over(Order by IDUnique) Row, IDUnique, ID, data  From #temp


DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR SET @getAccountID = CURSOR FOR SELECT Row_Number() Over(Order by IDUnique) Row, IDUnique, ID, data  From #temp
OPEN @getAccountID
FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @Row, @IDUnique, @ID, @data
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF(@Row = 1)
    Begin
        Set @Previous = @ID
        Set @Latest = @ID
        Insert into #temp1(ID, data)values(@Previous, @data)
    End
    Else If (@Previous <> @ID)
    Begin
        Set @Previous = @ID
        Set @Latest = @ID
        Insert into #temp1(ID, data)values(@Previous, @data)
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Declare @number int
        if(ISNUMERIC(@data) = 1)
        Begin
            Set @number = Convert(int , @data)
            While(@number <> 0)
            Begin
                Update #temp1 Set Data  = Data + ',-' Where ID = @ID
                Set @number = @number - 1
            End
        End
        Else    
        begin
            Update #temp1 Set Data  = Data + ',' + @data Where ID = @ID
        End
    End

    FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @Row, @IDUnique, @ID, @data
END
CLOSE @getAccountID
DEALLOCATE @getAccountID

Select * from #temp1
Select * from #temp
Drop Table #temp
```

here is the Final Result set

[image]

Comment: You are doing filtering for numeric and other then numeric values. That's why output is not correct. In order to move sequentially, I think you should move using cursor..